It feels like I have no chance to get into a physics phd program
I am a math major in the US who has done quite a lot of theory without any publications. My math grades are somewhat good but not As. I have always done research alone as my university did not have a High Energy physics program. I tried to work with professors at a nearby university many times during my 4 years in undergrad to no avail.
My problem is as follows: First, being an independent researcher, I have no one to write me any letters of rec. All the math professors I did do research with (1) is retired and I can't get a hold of him. Also, having no supervisor means I can't get Endorsed on Arxiv.org. I tried emailing professors I have taken classes with or researchers I have exchanged emails with and I am getting ghosted by everyone. There was a professor that promised he would take a look at my paper and provide feedback. I sent in the draft, and it's been around 1.5 months and nothing... I am not in town so I can't go to him personally. I also have been emailing him weekly and still nothing...
Then there is my current paper I am trying to finish before Dec when grad school applications are due. (As I figure the only way to show I am ready for grad school is to finish this as every other thing about doesn't prove I am "ready")
I have done research in High-energy theory. In my current paper, I am using Moduli space deformation that generates Gugino condensation and deforming G-structures with a non-vanishing first Chern class. The Torsion induced in G-structures that are non-integrable are almost all Kahler Manifolds described by Gromov-Witten invariants. I will show that ideas linked to complexity and other areas can possibly:

Shed light in mechanisms that break EW symmetry and SUSY in the soft sector

satisfy complex Einstein's equations for complex metrics and describe the role of "non-allowed" ones.

Describe the roles G2 structures have on physical observables and the role of "time in QG"
I hope that even though I am no expert in this field, I can use what I understand to contribute in any meaningful way.


Anyway, even if I finish it, I can't publish as I can't get an endorsement.
So... to cap it all off, I feel like I just have never (not for the lack of trying) gotten any chance to succeed in academia and I STILL feel like that is the case. I can't get any letters nor can I publish. I just wish I had some chance, any chance to increase my odds. How can it be not matter what I do, I can never succeed? (That is what a few professors who are currently ghosting me said)

In the last paragraph: your professors (plural) told you that "no matter what you do, you will never succeed"? That seems like a very strange thing for professors to say.

What happened last time you applied to a PhD program, what sort of feedback? PhD programs can be highly selective, that’s simply a fact.

No, unfortunately, US programs don't offer feedback.

Odd, I received honest but painful feedback back in the day. It certainly redirected the career path I had in mind at the time, all for the best. I suppose I’m starting to question this question. Good luck!

This question is similar to: How are Ph.D. applications evaluated in the US, particularly for weak or borderline students? Am I likely to get into school X?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Gugino condensation Do you mean gaugino?

done quite a lot of theory What does that mean? Have you taken standard undergraduate physics courses? If not, how do you expect to pass graduate-level physics courses and then your qualifying exams?

Undergraduates aren’t expected to be researchers. (Or they weren’t when I was an undergrad.) That’s what Ph.D. programs are for. A typical undergrad thesis in physics usually just demonstrates that one has studied some interesting topic and understood it reasonably well.

I sent in the draft, and it's been around 1.5 months and nothing. If that happened to me, I would interpret it as meaning that the professor didn’t see any merit in my paper, but finds it too awkward to tell me that.

The other answers have explained why you're having problems. You don't have a physics degree, your math grades are mostly not As, and whether your research is good is simply unknowable (the only way to tell is for an expert to slog through your papers, and vanishingly few will be willing to do so).
What I want to focus on is the other side: how do you fix it? Finishing your paper is probably not the right answer. As you say, you have no way of publishing the paper (even to the arXiv), and even if you managed to get it to the arXiv, it is unlikely to do you any good, since few experts will be willing to even evaluate it.
If you have not taken the standard upper-level physics courses (E&M, thermo, quantum, etc.), you will need to do so. You might be able to do this as part of a master's program, but if not, you may have to take these courses as a non-matriculated student. Once you have taken these courses and gotten good grades, your application will be a lot stronger. I realize taking these courses may be expensive, but if this is truly your dream, and you're not willing to consider other career paths, you may have to make sacrifices for it.
Once you have taken these courses, you can try applying again for PhD programs (don't neglect the less competitive schools; attending a lower-ranked school is fine so long as there is a suitable advisor for you). In parallel, I would also apply for master's programs. The former is probably better financially, while the latter has the advantage that if you are successful as a master's student, you can apply to more prestigious PhD programs. If you still think your current research ideas are viable, you can show them to your master's advisor. If they think your work is good, they can help you publish. And then you might be able to apply to the best graduate schools. Good luck.

I know of a few physics masters programs that focus on getting an undergraduate who did not major in physics ready for a physics PhD. But a middling math major without a strong background (demonstrated in courses) in physics is just not the way to get into a high energy physics PhD program.

I can offer some advice, but I'll assume you are interested in doctoral study in the US. For this and more generally, see the various answers to the canonical question on doctoral admissions.
First, note that published research is not generally (some exceptions) required for doctoral admissions in the US. Nor is it generally required that you come with a specific research problem. You don't need to choose a supervisor prior to admission. Note that changing fields from undergraduate to doctoral level is common and math -> physics is generally fine if you have had some physics courses in the undergrad, especially more than the minimum required for a math major.
Next, many, perhaps most R1 institutions in the US will have a good physics doctoral program and likely will have a few faculty with high-energy experience, and maybe even a working group. However, the first task, typically, is to take certain advanced courses to prepare for the very common qualifying exams. There might be (probably is) opportunity for a few extra courses, perhaps in HEP. But you will need to explore the offerings of places you apply to.
One applies to a department and one chooses a specialty later. I applied in math and would have been happy in either analysis or topology, but didn't need to specify even that for admission.
So, the first task is to get in the door, then pass exams, then comes the research with a specific advisor. And, some flexibility is needed in choice of problems, since the advisor must be "on-board" with any proposal.
Some things worry me about what you write here. You may be subverting yourself, actually. Sending weekly unanswered emails will get you tagged as a crank. It is sometimes difficult to distinguish between genius and crankiness. You may be too focused on things that aren't essential at this point. You need a good GPA and good letters of recommendation for entry.
An arXiv paper may mean nothing if it is unvetted. And papers take a long time to get published formally.
Some of the things you are attacking are very difficult without guidance and help (and possibly collaboration). This can lead to serious errors that you may have no way of recognizing, though I can't claim that is true in your case. But it could partly explain getting ghosted.
I do suggest, however, that you need an effective path to doctoral admission and what you write doesn't seem like it is anywhere near optimal for US programs. It might be in Germany and a few places, but those places also have very different and more focused undergraduate programs.
Finally, even with a fairly general physics doctorate, one can change focus later and will have resources to do so if you develop collaborative relationships.

I'm not a crank, I can't be a crank I never crank. YOU NEVER SEE ME WITH A CRANK!!!! AHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH

Glad you cleared that up.

Goodness knows what the media would say if they found out... OR THE SPACE PEOPLE (they are everywhere watching us)

Yep, I'm one of them, actually. Beware.

I always knew the dogs were from Outerspace. Checkmate..

but in all seriousness, I can't change my GPA (I graduated) and nothing else seems to be worth it as I can't get any letter of rec. It seems like all I can do now.

@BurakGuner: Nice, that pretty much settles things for me with this post. If nothing else you’ve experienced, and played with, the kindness and considerateness of others. Best of luck in your future endeavors elsewhere!

Research is really difficult. It's not like coursework, you can be very good at coursework and yet not be any good at research.
Except for a few rare geniuses, people learn how to do research from others who have more experience. Running through your post, you describe yourself as an "independent researcher" and mentioned areas that you've studied, but you also describe not having had anyone to learn from.
PhD admissions are not about giving a spot to everyone who might possibly be qualified, the admissions process distributes a limited number of funded opportunities to a selected group that is smaller than the number of qualified applicants. You are competing with all the other candidates. Some will have publications; others will not but will have letters from seasoned professors that describe their potential in research from firsthand experience.
If you don't have these things, why should you be chosen over them? It's not that you haven't been given a chance, it's that you've made several choices along the way that made your path far more difficult. You've attended an institution without a research focus in your area of interest. You've tried to get mentorship from professors whose job it is to mentor students at their institution, not yours. You've chosen to go it alone as an "independent researcher" without any guidance or feedback to know if any of the steps you are taking have any value.
I can't tell if your work has had any value, but the story you tell does not really inspire confidence. I do think from your description that you have a low probability of acceptance. Some people either consider it rude to offer honest strong negative feedback or fear a student's reaction if they do; it's possible that what you are perceiving as "ghosting" reflects these professors not being able to support you. If they say you are unlikely to succeed, I would not describe that as "ghosting": they're just politely telling you "no".

Actually, I did attend their university for a year, but I was considered out of state and had to switch to another university (the one I mentioned). So it was not my choice. also, you seem to say Independent research does not qualify me, but all research is done individually. You can't "teach" someone how to do research just as you can't teach someone how to imagine it just is.

@BurakGuner By "had to switch" do you mean "switched to save on tuition"? A PhD program is a program to teach students to do research. If you don't believe that's possible, it does not seem like you're a good fit to join a PhD program.

Please. if you want to ridicule me prove my ideas wrong don't attack me.

@BurakGuner What do you perceive as an attack? You've explained that you do not think research can be taught. Why would you then be interested in a research training program?

Graduate admissions without support from at least one academic is nearly a futile effort.
Step one is therefore to get mentorship from an academic. Given your circumstances, your odds are not good. You are probably best served by getting help from professors at your alma mater. Even if you graduated decades ago and the professors who taught you are no longer there, as long as the university still exists, there'll be professors who can help you.
There is also no requirement that you get "endorsement" to publish. You can always submit your paper to a journal, it's just a matter of passing the peer review process.
One undercurrent however is that you don't look like your work has merit, based solely on the fact that lots of people have talked to you and then ghosted you. As present, I would guess that even if you submit your paper to a journal, odds are you'll be desk rejected.
If you are serious about doing graduate studies, you'll need to be ready to take feedback, even if the feedback is [no] matter what [you] do, [you] can never succeed. Silver lining is that nobody is going to say that without due consideration, so they almost surely have given you feedback already, you just have to take it. What exactly did these people tell you before they broke off communications? I suggest reading it again and paying close attention.
